About verify signature with ed25519 issue
In my project, when trying to verify a signature with ed25519, I encountered an issue: 'Unknown program Ed25519SigVerify111111111111111111111111111',
or 'failed: program ed25519 sign verify not supported by inner instructions'.
#anchor test
...
Message: Transaction simulation failed: Error processing Instruction 0: An account required by the instruction is missing.
Logs:
[
  "Program log: Instruction: Deposit",
  "Program 11111111111111111111111111111111 invoke [2]",
  "Program 11111111111111111111111111111111 success",
  "Program 11111111111111111111111111111111 invoke [2]",
  "Program 11111111111111111111111111111111 success",
  "Program log: Verifying ed25519 signature",
  "Program log: ed25519_program::id: Ed25519SigVerify111111111111111111111111111",
  "Unknown program Ed25519SigVerify111111111111111111111111111",
  "Program 5APtDhWVsehsQM4yoqPTzy36EJJLRBLVxXy9ApCK6BeH consumed 35914 of 200000 compute units",
  "Program 5APtDhWVsehsQM4yoqPTzy36EJJLRBLVxXy9ApCK6BeH failed: An account required by the instruction is missing"
].
Catch the SendTransactionError and call getLogs() on it for full details.


@TercelYi's answer is correct, but it's missing an explanation about why you need to do it this way.
The ed25519 sig verify program performs the exact same signature verification as top-level signatures in a transaction, which is a computationally expensive operation that also costs 5000 lamports per signature.
If it were possible to CPI into the ed25519 program, then the runtime would also need a way to deduct 5000 lamports from the fee paying account.
So to make it easiest on the runtime, the ed25519 program only exists as a "precompile", meaning it's executed outside of the VM before the transaction is executed. Programs that wish to consume the result of the ed25519 program must inspect the instructions in the transaction, as in @TercelYi's answer.

The root cuase we can refer to @questions#13836's answer:
in tweetnacl-rust Is there a way to Verify(detached_verify) signature on contract side in rust?
The below code can verify signature.
use anchor_lang::prelude::*;
use crate::errors::ErrorCode;
use solana_program::sysvar::instructions::{load_instruction_at_checked, load_current_index_checked};


pub fn verify_ed25519_instruction(
    instruction_sysvar: &AccountInfo,
    expected_public_key: &[u8],
    message: &[u8],
    signature: &[u8]
) -> Result<()> {
    let current_index = load_current_index_checked(instruction_sysvar)?;
    if current_index == 0 {
        return Err(ErrorCode::MissingEd25519Instruction.into());
    }

    let ed25519_instruction = load_instruction_at_checked((current_index - 1) as usize, instruction_sysvar)?;
    
    // Verify the content of the Ed25519 instruction
    let instruction_data = ed25519_instruction.data;
    if instruction_data.len() < 2 {
        return Err(ErrorCode::InvalidEd25519Instruction.into());
    }

    let num_signatures = instruction_data[0];
    if num_signatures != 1 {
        return Err(ErrorCode::InvalidEd25519Instruction.into());
    }

    // Parse Ed25519SignatureOffsets
    let offsets: Ed25519SignatureOffsets = Ed25519SignatureOffsets::try_from_slice(&instruction_data[2..16])?;

    // Verify public key
    let pubkey_start = offsets.public_key_offset as usize;
    let pubkey_end = pubkey_start + 32;
    if &instruction_data[pubkey_start..pubkey_end] != expected_public_key {
        return Err(ErrorCode::InvalidPublicKey.into());
    }

    // Verify message
    let msg_start = offsets.message_data_offset as usize;
    let msg_end = msg_start + offsets.message_data_size as usize;
    if &instruction_data[msg_start..msg_end] != message {
        return Err(ErrorCode::InvalidMessage.into());
    }

    // Verify signature
    let sig_start = offsets.signature_offset as usize;
    let sig_end = sig_start + 64;
    if &instruction_data[sig_start..sig_end] != signature {
        return Err(ErrorCode::InvalidSignature.into());
    }

    Ok(())
}


#[derive(AnchorSerialize, AnchorDeserialize)]
struct Ed25519SignatureOffsets {
    signature_offset: u16,
    signature_instruction_index: u16,
    public_key_offset: u16,
    public_key_instruction_index: u16,
    message_data_offset: u16,
    message_data_size: u16,
    message_instruction_index: u16,
}

...
import * as anchor from "@coral-xyz/anchor";
import nacl from 'tweetnacl';
import {
  SYSVAR_INSTRUCTIONS_PUBKEY,
  Ed25519Program
} from "@solana/web3.js";

...
const signature = nacl.sign.detached(message, signerKeypair.secretKey);
const ed25519Instruction = Ed25519Program.createInstructionWithPublicKey({
      publicKey: signerKeypair.publicKey.toBytes(),
      message: message,
      signature: signature,
    });
    
    const tx = await program.methods
    .your_function(...)
    .accounts({
      ...
      instructionSysvar: SYSVAR_INSTRUCTIONS_PUBKEY,
      rent: anchor.web3.SYSVAR_RENT_PUBKEY,
    })
    .preInstructions([ed25519Instruction])
    .signers([payerKeypair])
    .rpc();


